# how to run particular test in headless mode in cypress in CI using windows schedular

Tags: cypress

tried :

```
yarn run cypress 'cypress/integration/**/*'
```

It didn't worked.

Also how can I run from windows scheduler particular set any one any idea?

Comment: To clarify your problem, better off leaving your failure log. It would be help others to look into and resolve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Shouldn't you call cypress like this: `cypress run --spec ......` if you want to specify specific tests?